# Google Fonts seem to be showing Comic Sans only on certain computers

Tags: css, google-fonts

I had a client calling and telling me that all their navigation fonts have turned to comic sans. This site has been out for about 3 years with really no updates since to it.  They sent me a screenshot of what they were seeing.

[image]

I have contacted multiple people to have them look at this site: https://www.westcapital.com/

No one else seems to be able to see the issue.  I don't know how to explain this to my  client as they are insistent that the site is broken even though it seems to be only computers in their office.  Any help would be appreciated on what i could say, or if other people are seeing it.  I've tried Safari, IE11, Edge, Firefox, and Chrome.  The screenshot is from Chrome on her computer.

Comment: Chrome 60 no repo. I don't see `comic-sans` in any of your style-sheets. Ask her for a screenshot of any log errors. Your fall-back font declaration is `Sans-Serif`; `Sans-Serif` is a generic declaration and include a number of different fonts.

Comment: The style says `font-family:'Unica One', cursive`, so it's just a matter of the webfont not loading. You can reproduce this behaviour by blocking `https://fonts.gstatic.com` in your ad blocker and reloading the page.

Comment: Isn't this just a clever spam attempt to lure us to the site???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an odd behaviour off a webpage - nothing programming related here.

Comment: It was a programming related question as I was asking if there was something with the programming that could cause this.  I was not trying to  spam anyone. I feel that comment is very unprofessional. I have found a lot of  commenters on Stack have been very unprofessional lately in regards to people asking questions or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the client was telling me it was on multiple computers, but it was theirs only. They were unsure what it was, but could have been ad blocker or the previous week they asked me for the font itself and they may of on accident overwrite the Unica One font with comic-sans.